# In Sending Email,Email template isnot working

Tags: trigger

I'am trying to send email template to the user.Email template isnot sending to that user.

[image]

```
 public class s360_InquiryUpdateDetails {
 public static void inquiryInformation(List < Opportunity > opList) {
set < id > primaryAccount = new set < id > ();
set < id > secondaryAccount = new set < id > ();
set < id > thirdAccount = new set < id > ();
map < id, string > primaryOppName = new map < id, string > ();
map < id, string > secondaryOppName = new map < id, string > ();
map < id, string > ThirdOppName = new map < id, string > ();

for (Opportunity op: opList) {
 //Primary Account
 if (op.AccountId != null) {
  primaryAccount.add(op.AccountId);
  primaryOppName.put(op.AccountId, op.Name);
 }
 //secondary
 if (op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c != null) {
  secondaryAccount.add(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c);
  secondaryOppName.put(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c, op.name);
 }
 //Third
 if (op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c != null) {
  thirdAccount.add(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c);
  ThirdOppName.put(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c, op.name);
 }
} // for loop en
map < id, id > primaryAccountMap = new map < id, id > ();
map < id, string > primaryAccountMap1 = new map < id, string > ();
map < id, id > secondaryAccountMap = new map < id, id > ();
map < id, string > secondaryAccountMap1 = new map < id, string > ();
map < id, id > thirdAccountMap = new map < id, id > ();
map < id, string > thirdAccountMap1 = new map < id, string > ();

for (Account ac: [SELECT id, name, Key_Account__c, Key_Account_Responsibility__c from Account where(id in : primaryAccount OR id in : secondaryAccount OR id in : thirdAccount)
  and Key_Account__c = true
 ]) {

 if (primaryAccount.contains(ac.Id)) {
  primaryAccountMap.put(ac.id, ac.Key_Account_Responsibility__c);
  primaryAccountMap1.put(ac.id, ac.name);



 } else if (secondaryAccount.contains(ac.Id)) {
  secondaryAccountMap.put(ac.id, ac.Key_Account_Responsibility__c);
  secondaryAccountMap1.put(ac.id, ac.name);
 } else if (thirdAccount.contains(ac.Id)) {
  thirdAccountMap.put(ac.id, ac.Key_Account_Responsibility__c);
  thirdAccountMap1.put(ac.id, ac.name);
 }

}
List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > mails = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > ();
for (Opportunity op: opList) {
 if (primaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId)) {
  mails.add(createEmailMessage(primaryAccountMap.get(op.AccountId), primaryAccountMap1.get(op.AccountId), primaryOppName.get(op.AccountId)));
 }
 if (secondaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId) && !primaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId)) {
  mails.add(createEmailMessage(secondaryAccountMap.get(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c), secondaryAccountMap1.get(op.AccountId), secondaryOppName.get(op.AccountId)));

 }
 if (thirdAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId) && !primaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId) && !secondaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId)) {
  mails.add(createEmailMessage(thirdAccountMap.get(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c), thirdAccountMap1.get(op.AccountId), ThirdOppName.get(op.AccountId)));

 }
}
system.debug('mails####' + mails);
Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}

private static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage createEmailMessage(String 
     userId, 
    string name, string OppName) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [Select Id, Name, HtmlValue, Body, Subject 
    from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'Global_Key_Account_Update'];
    String subject = emailTemplate.Subject;
    subject = subject.replace('{!Opportunity.Name}', OppName);
    subject = subject.replace('{!Account.Name}', name);
    String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HtmlValue;
    htmlBody = htmlBody.replace(' {!Account.Key_Account_Responsibility__c} ', userId);
    htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Opportunity.Name}', OppName);
    mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);
    mail.setTargetObjectId(userId);
    mail.saveAsActivity = false;
    //mail.setReplyTo('annappaph2@gmail.com');
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Test Mail');
    mail.setSubject('shawocr');
    String body = 'Test Mail';
    mail.setHtmlBody(body);

    return mail;
   }

  }
```

---

I have updated following code,but still itsnot working!!!!

```
 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [Select Id, Name, HtmlValue, Body, Subject from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'Global_Key_Account_Update'];
  String subject = emailTemplate.Subject;
  subject = subject.replace('{!Opportunity.Name}', OppName);
  subject = subject.replace('{!Account.Name}', name);
  String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HtmlValue;
  htmlBody = htmlBody.replace(' {!Account.Key_Account_Responsibility__c} ', userId);
  htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Opportunity.Name}', OppName);
   String plainBody = emailTemplate.Body;
   plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Account.Key_Account_Responsibility__c}', userId);
  plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Opportunity.Name}',OppName);
   mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);          
   mail.setPlainTextBody(plainBody);           
  mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);
  mail.setTreatBodiesAsTemplate(True);
  mail.setTargetObjectId(userId);
  mail.saveAsActivity = false;
  //mail.setReplyTo('annappaph2@gmail.com');
  mail.setSenderDisplayName('Test Mail');
  mail.setSubject('shawocr');
  String body = 'Test Mail';
  mail.setHtmlBody(body);
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception ..? Check your debug log..

Comment: iam not getting any exception.iam getting mail as well.but iam not getting email template in mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can specify either `setHtmlBody` or `setTemplateId` not both together.

As per doc, only `setHtmlBody` and `setPlainTextBody` can be used together otherwise you should specify only one. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm

> setHtmlBody(htmlBody)
>
> Optional. The HTML version of the email, specified by the sender. The
>   value is encoded according to the specification associated with the
>   organization. You must specify a value for setTemplateId, setHtmlBody,
>   or setPlainTextBody. Or, you can define both setHtmlBody and
>   setPlainTextBody.

Here is the related question if you want to create a template in apex: [How does setTreatBodiesAsTemplate(treatAsTemplate) work?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186081/how-does-settreatbodiesastemplatetreatastemplate-work)

Comment: I dont think thats the issue.Please check my updated code

Comment: Let me check  ...

Comment: I can see you are setting mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);   and as well as mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id); .... also mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody)  is written two times....   comment mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);  and give a try